# Invert incrementing triangle pattern

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, ascii-art

I am writing some code that creates a incrementing number right angle triangle that looks something like this:

```
           1
         1 2
       1 2 3
     1 2 3 4
   1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I am unsure on how to make my code output a triangle to that shape as my code outputs the same thing except inverted.

This is the code I have:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 6;
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

My speculation is that instead of incrementing some of the values I would decrement them however the code would run infinite garbage values and not what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is needed to print some spaces before printing the numbers in each row, and the number of spaces should be decreasing depending on the row:

```java
int rows = 6;

for (int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = rows - i; j >= 1; j--) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This prefix may be build using `String::join` + `Collections::nCopies`:

```java
System.out.print(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(rows - i, "  ")));
```

Or since Java 11, this prefix may be replaced using `String::repeat`:

```java
System.out.print("  ".repeat(rows - i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of two nested *for loops*, you can use a single *while loop* with two incrementing variables. The number of iterations stays the same.

```java
int n = 7, i = 0, j = 0;
while (i < n) {
    // element
    if (i + j >= n - 1) {
        // print an element
        System.out.print(i + j + 2 - n);
    } else {
        // print a whitespace
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    // suffix
    if (j < n - 1) {
        // print a delimiter
        System.out.print(" ");
        j++;
    } else {
        // print a new line
        System.out.println();
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
            1
          1 2
        1 2 3
      1 2 3 4
    1 2 3 4 5
  1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

---

<sup>See also: [Optimized Bubble Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66972347/15553668)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is almost correct - use two nested *for loops*, all that remains is to add one *if else statement* and calculate the `sum` of coordinates `i` and `j`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY7BCoMwEETvfsXiKSIKvfRi7R/05LH0kGqUpJqIiUIpfnu6QSmWSOlcBmbfzq6gE01Uz6SoHtb2473lJZQt1RoulEt4BYBac22oQZsUr6DDKSnMwGVzvQEdGh2tsBOXBiTkcMw@Ua0GIC7nmB8ytFMOEj2Ot5tfqFhQsaLCR52KpzasS9Vo0h7/MSSEMMo8zBXqscNKDjGIHaAG4oAzyMgb7h5ydIK038Vazf7r8J@dg18LrSQbfmHnYLb2DQ)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 6;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            int sum = i + j;
            if (sum > n)
                System.out.print(sum - n);
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
           1
         1 2
       1 2 3
     1 2 3 4
   1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

---

<sup>See also: [Printing a squares triangle. How to mirror numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68140941/16314724)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You have to print spaces before printing the numbers to make the triangle look inverted, the number of spaces depends on the amount of numbers you skip which are `rows-i`, so you can loop from `i` to `rows` and print space in each iteration.

```java
int rows = 6;
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j < rows; j++) {
        System.out.print("  ");
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
          1 
        1 2 
      1 2 3 
    1 2 3 4 
  1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property that for the row containing `i` as the greatest number of the row the number of the spaces can be calculated as `2*(rows-i)`. You can rewrite your program like below:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 6;
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i) {
            for (int nspaces = 0; nspaces < 2 * (rows - i); ++nspaces) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = i; j > 0; --j) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
          1 
        2 1 
      3 2 1 
    4 3 2 1 
  5 4 3 2 1 
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print an *inverted triangle* using two nested for-loops as follows:

```java
// the number of rows and the
// number of elements in each row 
int n = 6;
// iterating over rows with elements
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // iterating over elements in a row
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        // element
        if (i + j >= n - 1) {
            // print an element
            System.out.print(i + j + 2 - n);
        } else {
            // print a whitespace
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        // suffix
        if (j < n - 1) {
            // print a delimiter
            System.out.print(" ");
        } else {
            // print a new line
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
          1
        1 2
      1 2 3
    1 2 3 4
  1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to draw a staircase with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772762/15402945)</sup>